# SQL query with three tables and PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables in the database which are

### 1) order

```
id | oid | product
1 | 11 | product1 
2 | 12 | product2
```

### 2) order_qty

```
id | column3 | column2
1 | qty | 1
1 | xyz | value
1 | xyz | value
1 | xyz | value
1 | xyz | value
2 | qty | 2
2 | xyz | value
2 | xyz | value
2 | xyz | value
2 | xyz | value
```

### 3) order_detail

```
oid | column3 | column4
11 | name | krati
11 | phone | 1111
11 | xyz | value
11 | xyz | value
12 | name | JB
12 | phone | 2222
12 | xyz | value
12 | xyz | value
```

### I want to display these three tables with the values for id, product, qty, name and phone.

### This is my code :

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.product, b.column3, b.column2, c.column3, c.column4 FROM order a JOIN order_qty b ON a.id = b.id JOIN order_detail c ON a.oid = c.oid";
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["product"]; ?></td>
<td><?php if ($row["column3"] == 'qty') { echo $row["column2"]; } ?></td>
<td><?php if ($row["column3"] == 'name') { echo $row["column4"]; } ?></td>
<td><?php if ($row["column3"] == 'phone') { echo $row["column4"]; } ?></td>
</tr>
 }
```

### My Problem :

I fetch all the values but all the values are repeating with multiple rows, not able to get all the values in a single row

Example

```
1 product1 
1 product1
1 product1 2
1 product1     krati
1 product1 
1 product1            1111
```

### I want this

```
1 product1 1 krati 1111
2 product2 2 JB 2222
```

### Any solutions will be a great help to me as i have been trying this for 2 days.

### Edit

Column 3 is present in second and third table but with different values that is creating issue

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, a.product, b.column1, b.column2, c.column3, c.column4 FROM order a LEFT JOIN order_qty b ON a.id = b.id LEFT JOIN order_detail c ON a.oid = c.oid";
```

Comment: Still tha values are repeating..?

Answer (score 1):

Hi You have to use **subquery** for this
Check this and update ..

```
SELECT a.id, a.product, b.column2 as qty, (select column4 from order_detail where column3 = 'name' and oid = a.oid ) as name, (select column4 from order_detail where column3 = 'phone ' and oid = a.oid ) as phone FROM order a LEFT JOIN order_qty b ON a.id = b.id where b.column3 = 'qty'
```

Comment: Can you send me the results?

Comment: 1 product1 undefined index:column3 undefined index:column3 undefined index:column3

Comment: Is there is any possibility that there will be no name and no phone no ?

Comment: No it has values

Comment: I had checked it here it was working fine 
Please send me the whole query..

Comment: yes uh r right..column 1 is not there in second table, it is column 3 and i cant change it..please help

Comment: U have to change the name of columns 

Comment: i have edited the question..please check whether uh can do something..uh r almost there..thanx

Comment: @Peace Updated the answer please

Comment: Did not get the solution..But it's ok